# Se acumulan los seleccionados

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#tblClientes').DataTable({
    'select': true,
    'paging': true,
    'info': true,
    'filter': true,
    'stateSave': true,
    'processing': false,
    'serverSide': false,
    .....
});
});
```

Y el siguiente código también:

```
var mult_select = function(tbody, table){
$('#tblClientes tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

    table.on('select.dt', function() {
      var array = [];
      table.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx) {
         array.push(table.row(rowIdx).data())
      });   
      console.log(array);
    });
});
}
```

El objetivo es que al seleccionar un conjunto de filas pueda enviar por ajax el id de cada una de ella para hacer una consulta SQL.

El problema es que el console.log(array) cada vez que selecciono o deselecciono me muestra más y más, es como si se fuesen acumulando.
Quiero que cada vez que seleccione uno u dos (o más) me lo muestre todo en el mismo objeto dentro del array como el segundo desplegado de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano !!

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que quieres conseguir: Seleccionas una fila, se lanza el evento; seleccionas una segunda fila, el evento se lanza y ya tienes dos acumuladas... es normal que se vea eso en la consola, otra cosa es que quieras hacer menos consultas AJAX, pero tu código hace exactamente lo que declaras que quieres hacer

Comment: El objetivo final es poder seleccionar las filas que quiera y al darle a un botón lanzar un evento ajax (ya se para eliminarlas o lo que sea), el problema está probando seleccionar y deseleccionar filas para ver que me saca por consola, y cada vez me saca más y más, acumulándose. Se me llena la consola de seleccionar y deseleccionar solo dos filas.

Comment: ¿Para qué ocupas la función `every`? Esa se utiliza normalmente para testear una función a cada elemento del arreglo que mandó llamar la función. Más deberías de usar `each` porque con `every` si bien te funciona aquí, más adelante te puede dar funcionalidad indeseada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un contador y al añadir los datos al array, en vez de utilizar la función push indícale tú mismo el id a utilizar para guardarlo en el array.

```
var mult_select = function(tbody, table){
$('#tblClientes tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var id_array_seleccionados = 0;
    table.on('select.dt', function() {
      var array = [];
      table.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx) {
         array[id_array_seleccionados] = table.row(rowIdx).data();
         id_array_seleccionados++; //incrementas para el siguiente
      });   
      console.log(array);
    });
});
}
```